# performance impact of creating threads from inside of a thread in python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have a threaded application using `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and i want to create n number of threads from inside of each thread. Is it a good idea doing so ? How will it effect my resources like memory and CPU utililization ?  I tried but could find no relevant information on google.

Answer (score 0):

```
from concurrent import futures
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
import csv
import time


def casea():
    pools = {}
    for i in range(5000):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as executor:
            pools[executor.submit(middlemen)] = i

def caseb():
    pools = {}
    for i in range(5001,10000):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as executor:
            pools[executor.submit(writecsv, i)] = i


def middlemen():
    for k in range(5000):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
            pools[executor.submit(writecsv, k)] = k



def writecsv(i):
    nums = dict(zip(range(10000), range(10000)))
    filename = "test_{}.csv".format(i)
    fp = open(filename, 'w+')
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(nums)
    writer.close()
    fp.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = time.time()
    casea()
    t2 = time.time()
    print "Time taken CASE A: {}".format(t2-t1)
    t3 = time.time()
    caseb()
    t4 = time.time()
    print "Time taken CASE B: {}".format(t4-t3)

    # Time taken CASE A: 9.74694705009

    # Time taken CASE B: 35.9461958408
```

I used above code to do some benchmarking, seems using threads under threads giving 4x better performance